# Loading an Image file from Firebase Storage using SDWebImage

Tags: swift, firebase-storage, sdwebimage

I am trying to load an image from my Firebase Storage to be displayed on my app view.

I have 2 classes mainly

- Main "ClassView" that includes a tableView.
- A custom tableViewCell - "ClassCell" (This class includes an imageView where I want to display the picture from firestore. - imageView is called classImage.

Below is the tableView Data Source Extension.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.tableCellNibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.tableCellIdentifier)
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let reference = storageRef.child(K.FStore.classImagesPath)
    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")
    let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.tableCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ClassCell
    
        //below is where I try to set the my image but it is not changing anything
        cell.classImage?.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
      

       //This I tried to make sure that I am can access the image right and it worked just fine
       // cell.classImage?.backgroundColor = .black
    
    return cell
}
```

The Image is not displayed using the sd_setImage method. Any help would be highly appreciated if I have any error in my code or missing a declaration anywhere.

Below is what I am getting when I run the simulator. Instead of the image displayed in these black boxes, they are empty. Also, the imageView.image is returning nil so most probably the sd_setImage is not placing the image right.

[image: Class View]

Comment: What is this code actually doing, other than what you expect?  Please edit the question to be more clear and include your debugging details.

Comment: Make sure image you're trying to access is a ios supported format, not an SVG.

Comment: @Sreekuttan It is in JPG format. So I guess it is supported

Comment: @DougStevenson The code is not displaying any image. Only a white box is displayed. When I try accessing the imageView.image. It is giving nil. will add the details in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.imgSidebarMenuImage.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.whiteLarge
self.imgSidebarMenuImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (person["image"] as! String)), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

try this

#1

```
 let storage = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: “YOUR_PATH”)
       storage.downloadURL { (url, error) in
           if error != nil {
               print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
               return
       }
       print(“Download success”)
       
      //url = your will get an image URL
     self.someImageURL = url!
   }
```

#2

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                // cell identifier methods
 var item = itemData[indexPath.row]

      let referenceImage: StorageReference = storageRef.child("YOUR_PATH")
      let url = URL(string: referenceImage!)!
                    
                    
                    
cell.itemImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder"))

                }
            }

            return cell
    }
```

Comment: I aded the above line, but still I'm getting empty imageViews

Comment: @Zeyad is your image string correct ? or the format of your image is correct ?

Comment: The reference String in sd_setImage(with: reference) is exactly equal to the Storage location on Firestore. Does it maybe have something to do with the access token?

Comment: @Zeyad i edited my answer. Try any one of these. Hope it works.

Comment: How did you pass referenceImage of type StorageRef as a String in the following line?